# tarfile.extractall() raises IsADirectoryError because extraction path exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, tar

I am not able to extract a generated tar.gz file, since `extractall()` complains that the target directory exists. However, if the extraction directory does not exist, it simply generates an empty file.

All the examples I've found online about extracting a tarfile either [use no parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31163747/2891462) for `tarfile.extractall()` (which means it attempts to extract it in the same directory and fails for me with `IsADirectoryError`) or [make sure to create the extraction path beforehand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32952473/2891462).

This is using Python 3.5.2.

**Reproduction script:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import os, tarfile, tempfile

# Create a test directory
test_dir = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'tarfile-test')
os.makedirs(test_dir, exist_ok=True)
os.chdir(test_dir)

# Create empty files to include in the tarfile
open('1.txt', 'a').close()
open('2.txt', 'a').close()
open('3.txt', 'a').close()

# Create the tarfile
compressed_file = 'packet.tgz'
with tarfile.open(compressed_file, 'w:gz') as tar:
    for f in os.listdir():
        tar.add(f, arcname=os.path.sep)

# Now attempt to extract it in three different places: a local directory, a
# temporary directory and a non-existent directory

# Local directory
local_dir = 'local-extraction'
os.makedirs(local_dir, exist_ok=True)
try:
    with tarfile.open(compressed_file, 'r:gz') as tar:
        tar.extractall(path=local_dir)
        print('Extracted in local dir!')
except IsADirectoryError:
    print('Failed to extract in local directory')

# Temporary directory
try:
    with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tmp_dir:
        with tarfile.open(compressed_file, 'r:gz') as tar:
            tar.extractall(path=tmp_dir)
            print('Extracted in temporary dir!')
except IsADirectoryError:
    print('Failed to extract in temporary directory')

# Non-existent directory. This does not throw an exception, but fails to extract
# the files
non_existent = 'non_existent_dir'
with tarfile.open(compressed_file, 'r:gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall(path=non_existent)
    if os.path.isdir(non_existent):
        print('Extracted in previously non-existent dir!')
    else:
        print('Not extracted in non-existent dir')
```

Output:

```
$ ./repro.py 
Failed to extract in local directory
Failed to extract in temporary directory
Not extracted in non-existent dir
```

If we examine the contents of `tarfile-test`:

```
$ ll
total 16
drwxrwxr-x  3 user user 4096 Jul 11 08:38 ./
drwxr-xr-x 31 user user 4096 Jul 11 08:38 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 Jul 11 08:38 1.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 Jul 11 08:38 2.txt
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 Jul 11 08:38 3.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 Jul 11 08:38 local-extraction/
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user    0 Jul 11 08:38 non_existent_dir
-rw-rw-r--  1 user user  124 Jul 11 08:38 packet.tgz
```

`non_existent_dir` is an empty file, not a directory. `local-extraction` is empty.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is in the `arcname` parameter when creating the tar.gz file. I was (wrongly) following the advice [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032403/how-to-create-full-compressed-tar-file-using-python#comment72978579_17081026). However, that should only be done when packing a directory, it corrupts the tar.gz file is used when adding individual files.

Changing/removing the `arcname` parameter in `tarfile.add()` fixes it:

```
# Create the tarfile
compressed_file = 'packet.tgz'
with tarfile.open(compressed_file, 'w:gz') as tar:
    for f in os.listdir():
        tar.add(f)
```